# Custom component in IceFaces?

Tags: jsf, custom-component, icefaces, jsf-1.1

Who knows how to create a custom component in an old version of IceFaces 1.6.2? I didn't find anything in the web about that, just some materials about custom components for JSF 1.1. Please, show me simple "Hello World" custom component with file name and directory declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at http://www.exadel.com/tutorial/jsf/jsftutorial-customcomponents.html
 JSF Tutorial. You do not need special example for IceFaces 1.6.2, you can use IceFaces component within you own jsf component.